Proof Environment Inherits colour of theorem
I'm currently using the following setup with mdframed for theorems and proofs.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\definecolor{RoseDawn}{HTML}{d7827e}
\definecolor{GoldDawn}{HTML}{ea9d34}

%% Theorem style %%

\mdfsetup{skipabove=1em, skipbelow=0em}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries\color{GoldDawn!70!black}, 
    bodyfont=\normalfont,
    mdframed={
        linewidth=2pt,
        rightline=false, 
        topline=false, 
        bottomline=false,
        linecolor=GoldDawn, 
        backgroundcolor=GoldDawn!5,
    }
]{thmgolddawn}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries\color{GoldDawn!70!black}, 
    bodyfont=\normalfont,
    numbered=no,
    mdframed={
        linewidth=2pt,
        rightline=false, 
        topline=false, 
        bottomline=false,
        linecolor=GoldDawn, 
        backgroundcolor=GoldDawn!1,
    },
    qed=\qedsymbol
]{thmproofbox}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries\color{RoseDawn!70!black}, 
    bodyfont=\normalfont,
    mdframed={
        linewidth=2pt,
        rightline=false, 
        topline=false, 
        bottomline=false,
        linecolor=RoseDawn, 
        backgroundcolor=RoseDawn!5,
    }
]{thmrosedawn}

\declaretheorem[style=thmfoamdawn, name=Definition, numberwithin=section]{definition}
\declaretheorem[style=nostyle, name=Example, numberwithin=definition]{example}
\declaretheorem[style=thmgolddawn, name=Theorem, sibling=definition]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=thmrosedawn, name=Lemma, sibling=definition]{lemma}
\declaretheorem[style=thmirisdawn, name=Corollary, numberwithin=theorem]{corollary}
\declaretheorem[style=thmlovedawn, name=Proposition, sibling=definition]{proposition}

\declaretheorem[style=thmproofbox, name=Proof]{replacementproof}
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\vspace{-10pt}\begin{replacementproof}}{\end{replacementproof}}


\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
Proof by magic
\end{proof}
\end{document}

As can be seen, the proof environment has a lighter colour than that of the Theorem environment.
Ideally, I would like to have the same for my corollaries and lemmas etc, where the proof environment attached has a lighter colour.
In the best case, the proof environment could recognise the environment immediately above it and use the appropriate colour. Would this be possible?
If it is not, is there any method of manually declaring different proof environments. I tried using declaretheorem but didn't know how to implement the vspace{-10pt}. How would I be able to create a separate proof environment, such as corproof (corollary proof) that I could then use under my corollaries?

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Welcome! .......

Please, always check your code compiles and include the minimum necessary to demonstrate the issue.
I've not entirely minimised this, but I have removed a fair bit of unnecessary stuff. I also eventually figured out what I needed to add to get the thing to compile. Not everybody uses theorems sufficiently often to think about styling them.
What I would do would be to define a colour specifically for the proof boxes, thmproofboxcolour, say, set it to something globally (just in case) and then set it within each theorem style definition that you want to affect it. If you set up your colours in a standard way so that, for example, all styles use a base colour, 70% of that colour with 30% black and 5% of that colour, you only need a single such colour name. If, on the other hand, this may vary, you might need to use two or three such colour names.
We can use thmtools postfoothook when defining the style to set the colour appropriately. I've used red and gray in the example, as it saves loading all the xcolor names and because the two colours originally were too similar on my screen for me to distinguish them easily.
The catch is that this hook is executed still within the local group created by the theorem and colour definitions are local by default. So we need \xglobal\colorlet{thmproofboxcolour}{red} rather than just the standard \colorlet.
This has the disadvantage of changing the colour of the proof box globally i.e. it will stay red until changed to something else. Assuming a proof always follows some theorem-type construct and that the colour should always follow that of the theorem-type construct, this won't be a problem because it will be changed appropriately every time.
If, however, you have some cases where you want an independent colour for the proof, you will need to manage those separately, perhaps by resetting the colour explicitly. But I assume from your question such cases will be rare, if there are any at all.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\mdfsetup{skipabove=1em, skipbelow=0em}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\colorlet{thmproofboxcolour}{gray}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries\color{red!70!black}, 
    bodyfont=\normalfont,
    mdframed={
        linewidth=2pt,
        rightline=false, 
        topline=false, 
        bottomline=false,
        linecolor=red, 
        backgroundcolor=red!5,
    },
    postfoothook={\xglobal\colorlet{thmproofboxcolour}{red}},
]{thmgolddawn}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries\color{thmproofboxcolour!70!black}, 
    bodyfont=\normalfont,
    numbered=no,
    mdframed={
        linewidth=2pt,
        rightline=false, 
        topline=false, 
        bottomline=false,
        linecolor=thmproofboxcolour, 
        backgroundcolor=thmproofboxcolour!5,
    },
    qed=\qedsymbol,
]{thmproofbox}


\declaretheorem[style=thmfoamdawn, name=Definition, numberwithin=section]{definition}
\declaretheorem[style=thmgolddawn, name=Theorem, sibling=definition]{theorem}

\declaretheorem[style=thmproofbox, name=Proof]{replacementproof}
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\vspace{-10pt}\begin{replacementproof}}{\end{replacementproof}}


\begin{document}
\begin{proof}% of nothing, but just to demonstrate the colour isn't red to start
  Proof by trial
\end{proof}
\begin{theorem}% red and changes the proof colour to red
  This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}% red because that's the colour the theorem set it to
  Proof by magic
\end{proof}
% all proofs now red until a differently styled environment changes it
% e.g. presumably you will add suitable hooks for lemmas, definitions etc.
\end{document}



Thanks! This is perfect!
